# Why is tableView:heightOfRow: called for each row?

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

When I populate my view-based NSTableView, the method `tableView:heightOfRow:` is called for each of the objects that are coming from the data source, no matter how many of them are actually on display. Does this mean that all the views are actually created?

Note: in my implementation of `tableView:heightOfRow:` I'm not creating any view, I'm just calculating the height from an `NSString`.

EDIT: This is a cocoa project.

Comment: `tableView:heightOfRow:` is used for (1) sizing your cells but also (2) determining the overall size of the tableview, so that things like the scroll indicators work correctly. Calling `tableView:heightOfRow:` won't instantiate any views, or call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` unless you explicitly do so.

Comment: if you need to do some heave calculations like autosizing text, it's better to use estimatedHeight:

Comment: Thank you both! I'm looking into your suggestions.

Comment: @rickerbh Seems your point about scroll indicators ought to be an answer.